# секундомер, который показывает время другого секундомера

Tags: java, таймер

я хочу, что бы в случае повторного запуска кода (или другого кода), запускался секундомер с текущим значением ранее запущенного секундомера, как это возможно реализовать? пробовал `setDelay`, получилось как-то по криворукому. может как-то возможно сохранять/передавать значение секундомера?
код таймера:

```html
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Stopwatch implements ActionListener{


        JButton button = new JButton("knopka");
        JFrame frame_timer = new JFrame();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton startButton = new JButton("start");
        JButton resetButton = new JButton("reset");
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
        int elapsedTime = 0;
        int seconds =0;
        int minutes =0;
        int hours=0;
        boolean started = false;
        String seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
        String minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
        String hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours); 
    
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                elapsedTime=elapsedTime+1000;
                hours = (elapsedTime/3600000);
                minutes = (elapsedTime/60000)%60;
                seconds = (elapsedTime/1000)%60;
                seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
                minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
                hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours);
                
                timeLabel.setText(hours_string+":"+minutes_string+":"+seconds_string);
            }
            
            
        });
        
        public Stopwatch(){
            
            timeLabel.setText(hours_string+"-"+minutes_string+"-"+seconds_string);
            timeLabel.setBounds(100,100,200,100);
            timeLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.PLAIN,35));
            timeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
            timeLabel.setOpaque(true);
            timeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    
            startButton.setBounds(100,100,200,50);
            startButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,20));
            startButton.setFocusable(false);
            startButton.addActionListener(this);
            
            resetButton.setBounds(100,150,200,50);
            resetButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,20));
            resetButton.setFocusable(false);
            resetButton.addActionListener(this);
            
            frame.add(startButton);
            frame.add(resetButton);
            frame.add(timeLabel);
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(420,420);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
            frame_timer.add(timeLabel);
            frame_timer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame_timer.setSize(420,420);
            frame_timer.setLayout(null);
            frame_timer.add(timeLabel);
            frame_timer.setVisible(true);
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            if(e.getSource()==startButton) {
                start();
                if(started==false) {
                    started=true;
                    startButton.setText("stop");
                    start();
                }
                else {
                    started=false;
                    startButton.setText("continue");
        
                    stop();
                }
            }

                        if(e.getSource()==resetButton){
                started=false;
                startButton.setText("start");
                reset(); }
                }
    
        
void start() {
    timer.start();
    }
void stop() {
    timer.stop();
}
void reset() {
    timer.stop();
    elapsedTime=0;
    seconds=0;
    minutes=0;
    hours=0;
    seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
    minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
    hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours);
    timeLabel.setText(hours_string+":"+minutes_string+":"+seconds_string);
}


public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}


public static Object getDelay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: может создать один глобальный секундомер? только как правильно написать?

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно. Я смотрю вы не ровно дышите к таймерам. Ну если подумать, то чтобы след программа началась, там где закончилась старая, данные надо где-то хранить, либо в файле, либо в базе. Можно записывать показания таймера с интервалом в файл, но надо будет решать проблему доступа к файлу нескольких потоков одновременно, потому что след. программа может быть запущена при работающей уже программе, и они будут конфликтовать, если правильно не реализовать

Comment: @ScruffytheJanitor, хахаха, да таймеры я люблю. возможно это реализовать с `System.currentTimeMillis` ?  я предполагаю, что можно сделать так, в случае запуска второго секундомера, сначала код запрашивает текущее время секундомера, после этого уже запускает секундомер с параметром `setText(System.currentTimeMillis);`

Comment: Так это просто время вашей операционной системы,   таймер это не просто часы, его выставляют на определённый период, ставят на паузу, ускоряют. Он по своей задумки не должен быть постоянно равен текущему времени иначе это просто часы

Comment: @ScruffytheJanitor хорошо, не таймер, а секундомер. тогда я все равно не догоняю, как мне получить значение секундомера, пока он выполняется? как передать это значение новому секундомеру в принципе ясно

Comment: С секундомером тоже самое. Он равен нулю изначально, пока не замерить отрезок времени. Если бы следующая программа знала когда запустился предыдущий секундомер, тогда бы ваш вариант с текущем временим ОС пригодился бы. Можно было бы получить разность, и эта разность и была бы текущем значением нового секундомера

Comment: то есть, можно сделать, что бы программа записывала текущее время ОС, присваиваем это время к какой то переменной. после того как запустился новый секундомер, он снова записывал текущее время в ОС, считал разность и начинал отчет уже с того времени? с таким методом задержка может быть в несколько секунд? этот вариант не подходит, в случае если секундомер остановят или сбросят, значение на втором секундомере будет неверно

Comment: Ну я описал вам только первый шаг, решите его, дальше усложняйте функционал. А как вы себе это представляете по другому? Вам нужно хранилище данных в любом случае

Comment: подскажите, а можно как то сделать, что бы код второй раз открывал просто уже запущенный секундомер? @ScruffytheJanitor

Comment: Как и написал в коментах выше если речь идёт об функциях остановки таймера, тогда надо будет постоянно с маленький интервалом записывать и читать файл который представляет базу  данных, а это приведёт к коныликтам. Ну для вас самый простой вариант это просто подключить базу данных какую-то, чтоб не заморачиааться с доступом к файлу

Comment: Запущенный секундомер это java программа, вы хотите, что новая программа открыла уже запущенню? Речь идёт об обмене данными между программами, гуглите в этом направлении, лично  я себе представляю только несколько вариантов обмена, сокеты, база данных

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант. При запуске секундомер сохраняете текущее время системы в файл, при открытии новой программы если в файле уже есть время и оно не равно нулю, значит вычитание из текущего времени системы, то что было в файле, получаете данные первого секундомера и работаете. Дальше добавляйте функционал и решайте проблемы по мере поступления. Если вы хотите, чтоб после закрытия таймера, другая программа начала с того же места, без хранилища данных очевидно не обойтись. Если только не воспользоваться клиент сервером из пред. вашего вопроса при условии, что сервер всегда будет работать. По сути решение уже изложенно было в вашем предыд. вопросе, добавьте к серверу хранилище и все, какие проблемы.